# Split string at different size

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have a string like this one:

`var s = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet';`

I want an array like this one:

```
var l = [3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 1, 2, 1];
var a = ['Lor', 'em ', 'ips', 'u', 'm ', 'dolor', ' sit', 'a', 'me', 't'];
```

The subdivisions do not have the same length.

I know a priori that I want the first element to have length 3 (`Lor`), the second 3 (`em`), the third 3 (`ips`), the fourth 1 (`u`), the fifth 2 (`m`), the sixth 5 (`dolor`), the seventh 4 (`sit`), the eighth 1 (`a`), the ninth 2 (`me`) and the tenth 1 (`t`).

How can I do?

Comment: where do you get the length series from?

Comment: @NinaScholz For example, from an array. I edit my main message

Comment: there is a space between `sit amet` you ignore in your array `a`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could map the single length parts.

It works with a closure over the last position `p`

```
(p => i => string.slice(p, p += i))(0)
(p =>                             )(0) // call function with zero as p and return cb
      i => string.slice(p, p += i)     // callback for map
```

```js
var lengths = [3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 1, 2, 1],
    string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    result = lengths.map((p => i => string.slice(p, p += i))(0));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do. but your question is confusing; the 3rd from last element is 2 in length, not 1.

```js
var s = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet';

var a = ['Lor', 'em ', 'ips', 'u', 'm ', 'dolor', ' sit', 'a', 'me', 't'];

var splitAt = [3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2, 2, 1];

function splitByLengths(str, arr){
  var id = 0;
  var outputArr = [];
  arr.forEach(function(len){
    outputArr.push(str.slice(id, id+len));
    id += len;
 
  });
  return outputArr;
}
console.log(splitByLengths(s, splitAt));
console.log("as expected?", splitByLengths(s, splitAt) === a);
```